# Im getting an error where it says my list is empty when it isn't

Tags: python, random

Im creating a word jumble game and im getting an issue where it says my while loop is empty i could really use with some help heres my code thanks.

```
import random

count = 0

word = 'index'
wordLength = (5)

print('the word is', word ,'\n')

high = len(word)
low = -len(word)

for i in range(15):
    position = random.randrange(low, high)

listf = [0,1,2,3,4]

randomletter = random.choice(listf)


for each in range(wordLength):
    while count < 6:

        if randomletter == 0:
            listf.remove(0)
            randomletter = random.choice(listf)
            print(word[0])
        elif randomletter == 1:
            print(word[1])
            listf.remove(1)
            randomletter = random.choice(listf)
        elif randomletter == 2:
            print(word[2])
            listf.remove(2)
            randomletter = random.choice(listf)
        elif randomletter == 3:
            print(word[3])
            listf.remove(3)
            randomletter = random.choice(listf)
        elif randomletter == 4:
            print(word[4])
            listf.remove(4)
            randomletter = random.choice(listf)
        count += 1


inputs = input('press enter to exit')
```

Here is the error i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 230, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/sec.student/Y9/Y9B/Oliver McLean/jumbler2.0.py", line 43, in <module>
    randomletter = random.choice(listf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 255, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: Errors don't lie. You may want to debug your code again

Comment: Your `while` loop loops six times but your list only has five entries. `while count < 6 and listf:` should prevent the error, but it would be better to fix your logic.

Comment: why are you bothering with a `count` when you can just do `while listf:` and getting the `randomletter` at the top of the loop instead of inside **every** conditional.